# Saving a HTML table form into a text file using PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, html-table

I am trying to make a sign-up form where a user enters their name into a time slot. Then the names are saved into a text file but it is not being saved into the text file.

HTML form party

```
<form action="writeit.php" method="POST" name="nameform">
<table style="width:20%">
<tr>
<th>Time</th>
<th colspan="2">Name</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>8:00am</td>
<td><input type="text" name="name" id="name"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>9:00am</td>
<td><input type="text" name="name" id="name"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>10:00am</td>
<td><input type="text" name="name" id="name"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>11:00am</td>
<td><input type="text" name="name" id="name"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>12:00pm</td>
<td><input type="text" name="name" id="name"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1:00pm</td>
<td><input type="text" name="name" id="name"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2:00pm</td>
<td><input type="text" name="name" id="name"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3:00pm</td>
<td><input type="text" name="name" id="name"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>4:00pm</td>
<td><input type="text" name="name" id="name"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>5:00pm</td>
<td><input type="text" name="name" id="name"></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br></br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

the writeit.php file

```
<?php

$names = $_POST['name'];
$filename = "signup.txt";
$file = fopen($filename, "a");
fwrite($file, $names);
fclose($file);

?>
```

Comment: You can't have form elements with the same `name` attribute. `$_POST['name']` won't know which one to use. Try giving a unique name, or setting them as an array with `name[]`.

Comment: Okay I tried giving them all unique names then tried to save just the first name, that didn't work.

Then I changed them all to name[] and changed the post to ['name'][0], to just try and save the first name and that didn't work either.